# "Have" or "had" in "She told them to raise their hands if they HAVE a question"?

Tags: reported-speech

My problem is regarding indirect speech.

> She told them to raise their hands if they **have** a question.

Is this sentence grammatically wrong?

If this sentence is correct, is there basis or evidence?

Many students learned in their academy 'had' instead of 'have'.

So I must show them why that sentence is correct.

But I don't have any evidence or basis.

Comment: Your post was changed a little for clarity. If [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/85344/mimi) is your unregistered account and you would like to merge your two accounts, see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous). See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips on asking questions.

Comment: It should be "She told them to raise their hands if they **had** a question."

Answer (score -3):

Your sentence is correct.  The understanding your classmates have about "had" is incorrect.

"Had" is *past perfect*.  That means it's an event that *was* true, but is not *currently* true.  Let's ignore the indirect speech for a moment, and convert the sentence to direct speech; that is, the command form.

> Raise your hand if you have a question.

Compare this to:

> Raise your hand if you had a question.

In this second sentence, the teacher is saying that if you had a question, *but don't have a question now*, you should raise your hand.  This meaning is nonsense, and clearly not intended.  The teacher says "have a question" because she wants you to raise your hand in order to ask the question that you *still have*.

Converting it into indirect speech, you must keep the same tense as the statement made in direct speech.  Thus, "have" is correct.

Comment: "You must keep the same tense." This is wrong—and your analysis is misleading. Reported speech is *always* correct in the past tense. But if what is being reported is a general truth or *still* true, then the present tense is *also* fine, yet optional. (Although some people object to it anyway.) For instance, "She said the earth is round" is fine. But "My dead friend said he is hungry" is not.